# Profiling Django RPC calls (Same as Django debug toolbar)

Tags: django, json-rpc, django-debug-toolbar, appstats

I have an application which calls Django RPCs using jsonrpclib. I need to implement some kind of profiling for these RPCs, similar to Django debug toolbar, but in this case there is no rendering of html pages.

I have no idea where to start, I am looking for stats such as time spent on the RPC call, no. of queries fired by each RPC.

I checked google appstat and need something similar: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

It would be great if someone can suggest what changes need to be done to django debug toolbar library itself to make it profile for RPC calls.

Or are there any other libs already present out there?